# Can I give a different number of points to each `schoice` exercise in R `exams`?

Tags: r, r-exams

How can I give a different number of points to each exercise in an exam produced with the `exams` package using the function `exams2nops`? I already created the exam, and my question is if I can use a vector of `expoints` when using the `nops_eval` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points can be specified at various levels:

- Within the **exercise** via the `expoints` tag. Default if no such tag: 1 point.
- When creating the **exam** with `exams2nops(..., points = ...)` (or other `exams2xyz` interfaces). Default: Use points from the exercise.
- In the **evaluation** of the exam via `nops_eval(..., points = ...)`. Default: Use points from the exam.

Thus, the points specification is always called `points` except in the tag within the exercise where the `ex` prefix is added for all R/exams tags.

In the exam and the evaluation `points` can be a vector of different points for each exercise.